# CLANG: Suppressing runtime warnings

Tags: objective-c, clang, c-preprocessor, pragma

I get runtime warnings when I do things like access a UIView's `.center` property from a background thread.

With traditional xCode warnings I can suppress them using CLANG like so:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
//code triggering warning
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

However, this -Weverything flag does not work for runtime warnings (contrary to its name and implied documentation),

Does anyone know a compiler flag that can be set via clang / pragma preprocessors that will silence runtime warnings as well?

P.s. I am aware I can disable them in Xcode but I need a CLANG solution so I can disable them on specific lines w/ ease using my macros.

Comment: It’s not the compiler giving these out so it cannot disable them. It’s the operating system and you should rather listen to the warnings and not try to hide them. The flag is completely properly named and documented.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen For something as trivial as reading the `.center` of a UIView, this can be done in the background thread without need for warning every time I compile. My app uses many threads and pushing this method into the main thread would cause un-necessary lag.

Comment: So you know this better than the people who made the UI framework? Better contact Apple about it and ask them to remove this if it’s not needed. Otherwise just live with the warnings or change your code not to touch it in a background thread. If you need to it usually means there’s a bad design choice somewhere, especially if you need to just read it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen This is not productive to my question. I am not claiming to know UI Framework better than its devs, all I was saying is the worst case scenario of reading a view's .center property on background thread is it is out of sync by 1 cycle or so, for my application this will never matter as they are static anyways so I can safely suppress the warning. Just need to know _how_.

Comment: You disable it by not doing this. Why not save the information on a variable you can read from other threads?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen This is not at all relevant to my question, you don't know our source code so interjecting on coding practices for our one specific problem is silly. Obviously CLANG allows you to suppress almost every other warning and there are reasons for doing such, if there were not, then `diagnostic ignored` would not be a thing, yet it has been included because even the developers of these languages know that there is a time and place for doing things like this, for you to suggest there isn't goes against their own design since they themselves made `diagnostic ignored`.

Comment: As I said, runtime warnings don’t come from the compiler. Clang has nothing to do with them. At least I have never seen such a thing. You haven’t included an exact example of the warning so hard to say. And yes, you haven’t explained much of your use case so there’s not much anyone can say.

Comment: I have not included my code because this is not CodeReview SE. I am asking a specific question about suppressing a warning. My code and/or use-case is irrelevant. There are many ways to suppress many warnings, I am simply asking if one is known for suppressing runtime warnings.

Comment: As I’ve said, no. *Clang can’t suppress them.* It has nothing to do with them. If you don’t want to fix your code, I apologize for suggesting such things. The only option then is either to live with them and risk buggy results, or ask Apple to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting "Runtime API checking" "[ ] Main Thread checker" in "Edit Scheme..." > Diagnostics. Disabling that should silence the warning.

Comment: I saw this setting when researching but it seems there is no way to disable it just for specific lines of code like you can with clang diagnostic?